# Is there a way to optimize finding element inside a Map with java stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a hashmap composed of a string as a key and an object list as a value. I need to extract records that have a specific string as a key from this list. Also in the list of values ​​contained in each record I need records that have a particular attribute set to true.

I have already developed a working solution with java streams. Since this code is used within a critical task regarding execution times I was wondering if it was not possible to optimize my code to make it faster.

```
private HashMap<String, List<RewriteBase>> rewriteUrl;

public static class RewriteBase {
    @NotNull
    private String  urlRegex;
    @NotNull
    private String  proxyPres;
    private boolean enable;
    private boolean insensitive;
}

Map<String, List<RewriteBase>> rewriteBaseList = GetRewriteUrl();

Map<String, List<RewriteBase>> result = rewriteBaseList.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(valore -> path.startsWith(valore.getKey()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, p -> p.getValue().stream()
    .filter(value -> value.isEnable()).collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

Data source:

```
rewriteUrl:
    '[/urla/urlb/sc]':
    -
        urlRegex: /prea/sc
        proxyPres: /evm
        enable: true
        insensitive: true
    -
        urlRegex: header-logo
        proxyPres: /evm
        enable: false
        insensitive: true
    '[/urlc/urld/sc/filter]':
    -
        urlRegex: /utlnot/sc
        proxyPres: /evm
        enable: true
        insensitive: true
```

This is the yml file that is mapped in the RewriteBase class and inserted into the HashMap rewriteUrl. Assuming that the key to find for is "/urla/urlb/sc" I expect as a result a HashMap with "/urla/urlb/sc" as a key and as a value a list containing only the record with enable set to true. In practice this:

```
rewriteUrl:
    '[/urla/urlb/sc]':
    -
        urlRegex: /prea/sc
        proxyPres: /evm
        enable: true
        insensitive: true
```

Currently I get the right result but I think my code can be improved and made faster.

Comment: Wrong website. This belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The two traversals (i.e. one of map entries and another of the list of values within those entries) are almost unavoidable, but you can possibly make it more readable and avoid collecting as :

```java
rewriteBaseList.keySet().removeIf(k -> !path.startsWith(k)); // updating the source map
rewriteBaseList.values().removeIf(v -> v.removeIf(r -> !r.isEnable()) && v.isEmpty());
```

Comment: *optimize my code to make it faster.* .. I wouldn't really say this would make it faster unless there is a derived comparison of the two in benchmarks. But yeah, the `Collector` was something that struck to me as an unnecessary call in your pipeline.

Comment: Mind that `removeIf` has the opposite condition than `filter`. Besides that, when you don't use the key, you can also use `rewriteBaseList.values().forEach(v -> v.removeIf(r -> !r.isEnable()));` which is neat when extending it to `rewriteBaseList.values().removeIf(v -> v.removeIf(r -> !r.isEnable()) && v.isEmpty());`, to remove entries when no enabled rules are left.

Comment: @Holger Condition was just a typo, a similar approach was followed while writing the first `Predicate`. Thanks for the `values.removeIf`, makes much sense and I was wondering while posting the answer if the return type of `removeIf` could be used somehow, you showed me the way. Thanks again.